# How can I use one template for JSP and JS Underscore?

Tags: javascript, jsp, underscore.js, lodash

I have one graphical layout which will be rendered in different places both:

- on client side by JavaScripts' templates (underscore)
- on server side by JSP

The layout will be exactly the same so I would like to omit duplication of code and use one template file for both.

How can I do it?

Comment: Perhaps you want to further clarify what you want to achieve? This is because in some scenarios, Handlebars might be helpful to you.

Comment: Can you tell me in what scenarios Handlebars would be useful?